# Which path context when using Handlebars {{embedd}} includes

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

Im trying to use the helper described here:
http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-code.html

Using something like:
`{{embed './forms/verticalforms.html'}}`

However after trying many options, no matter which paths I use on the include I cant get the output to include the html of the embedded file. I thin this means it isn't getting into the file but im not understanding why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the full path from the root of the project to the file you want to embed (include). From appearances it looks like you're using a relative path.

Comment: I had tried both relative and absolute paths, but didn't knew it was supposed to be relative to the gruntfile location.